# How can I find the location of android.support.v7 library in my computer?

Tags: java, android, windows, location, libraries

**I wanted to use ImageView as a parent class in my code. But since it was not supported I used the suggestion and extended android.support.v7.widget.AppCompactImageView but my AppCompactImageView came to appear as not resolved. So I realized that android.support.v7.widget didn't contain AppCompactImageView. Therefore, I was trying to find from where my code accessed android.support.v7.widget and insert AppCompactImageView in it manually from internet. But I couldn't figure out how and where these files are stored.**

*I have tried searching all the related folders in my windows 10. My search was either support, or widget, just to get a hint where it was located. But didnt find so.*

- public class LetterImageView extends ImageView{}

ERROR HERE: The custom view should extend android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView instead.

---

- public class LetterImageView extends
  android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{}

ERROR HERE: Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatImageView.

Comment: `ERROR HERE: The custom view should extend android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView instead.` => `SOLUTION HERE: The custom view should extend android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView instead.`

Answer (score 0):

Two options can be possible

1) If you are using target version 29 with android studio 3.5 then you should import

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView/>
```

not V7 Imageview

2) If you are using lower version of android studio than first option then you can check external libraries option

[image]